# Can't Autowire ThreadPoolTaskExecutor form spring.boot.autoconfigure.task

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I try to use spring's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. I found bean created in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task`, but I can't autowire it to my Component.

```
public class TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration {

...

@Lazy
@Bean(
            name = {"applicationTaskExecutor", "taskExecutor"}
        )
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({Executor.class})
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorBuilder builder) {
            return builder.build();
    }
}
```

and I try to Autowire it by Qualifier

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor")
public void setThreadPoolTaskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor) {
        this.threadPoolTaskExecutor = threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```

but I IDE talking that he could not find this bean. 
What am I don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@AutoWired` annotation to inject the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Then use the `@PostConstruct` annotation to set the properties. The sample code is as below.

```
package com.example.workers;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
   public class EmailComponent {
    private class MessagePrinterTask implements Runnable {

        private String message;

        public MessagePrinterTask(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5); //or read from properties file
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
    }

    public EmailComponent() {

    }
    public void startJob() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            executor.execute(new MessagePrinterTask("Message" + i));
        }
    } 






 }
```

Comment: I would avoid changing the executor's attributes in post construct since you're changing a shared instance which might be used in other areas of the application as well, and I am not sure it is intended in this specific case,
Instead - I would recommend on inheriting / extending the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with a new custom class (MyNewThreadPoolTaskExecutor), putting @Component on it and setting the attributes there

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `@Lazy` annotation when use it.

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor")
public void setThreadPoolTaskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor) {
        this.threadPoolTaskExecutor = threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
```